# iPhone/iPad Encrypting JSON

Tags: iphone, json, encryption

I want to encrypt some json from a server and then decrypt it on the iphone/ipad. What are your thoughts on this? What is the best approach to this? Should I scrap this idea and just go via SSL?

Comment: What are you trying to protect ? The user will always be able to see the data somehow, if you need it to be decryptable on the client. If you want to protect information sent between parties: By all means, go with SSL, don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: the user will see the decrypted json so I just want to protect the information in between.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save yourself a lot of trouble and just use HTTPS for all server communications.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above one way is to do everything over https.

An alternative I can think of is the following:

1. Generate an symmetrical encryption
   key per session/login per client on
   the server
2. Send that key to the client over
   **https**
3. From there on encrypt all the data
   you send to the client with that key
4. The client can then decrypt the
   encrypted data

I don't have enough knowledge about https. I often read that is heavy on the resources of the system, but since I have not made or read some good benchmarks I can't give you a rigorous argument for or against it.

The implementation I proposed require a little bit more coding, but you can tailor to your encryption needs.

I think ultimately your decision should be made based on your usage scenario, if you sent very little data, not often to a few client application, you can't go wrong with https. If your expected encrypted traffic is high, the alternative solution might make sense.

Comment: The data isn't that large but it updates every 60 seconds. I guess ill just stick to https. cheers.